# Android Camera2 api for recording not working

Tags: android, video, recording, android-camera2

I am trying to record video using the Camera2 API. But there is some exception thrown about lost surfaces. I cross-checked that the surface view exists in XML and all permissions are set too. I tried using the Google Camera2 code but not able to understand all bits and pieces.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    CameraDevice mCamera;
    MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    CaptureRequest mCaptureRequest;
    CameraCaptureSession mSession;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean recording = false;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);

        File directory = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        String path = String.valueOf(directory);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        final File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(directory + File.separator + timeStamp + ".mp4");

        try {
            String[] cameras = manager.getCameraIdList();
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameras[0]);
            StreamConfigurationMap configs = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            Size[] sizes = configs.getOutputSizes(MediaCodec.class);
            final Size sizeHigh = sizes[0];

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameras[0], new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                    mCamera = camera;

                    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
                    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
//                    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(sizeHigh.getWidth(), sizeHigh.getHeight());
//                    mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(0);
//                    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(0);

                    try {
                        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mediaFile.toString());
                        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
                        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
                        List<Surface> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
                        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequest = mCamera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
                        captureRequest.addTarget(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
                        mCaptureRequest = captureRequest.build();
                        mCamera.createCaptureSession(list, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                mSession = session;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                mSession = session;
                            }
                        }, null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {

                }
            }, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    public void trigger(View v) {


        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setText("stop");
        try {
            if(!recording) {
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                mSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequest,
                        new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCaptureStarted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, long timestamp, long frameNumber) {
                                super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                            }
                        }, null);

                ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setText("stop");
                recording = true;
            } else {
                ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setText("start");
                recording = false;
                mSession.stopRepeating();
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


Exception Thrown

07-31 22:43:30.650 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera I/System.out:      debugger has settled (1492)
07-31 22:43:30.972 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
07-31 22:43:31.036 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera I/CameraManager: Using legacy camera HAL.
07-31 22:43:31.170 2852-3618/com.example.karan.camera D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
07-31 22:43:31.191 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera E/MediaRecorderJNI: Application lost the surface
07-31 22:43:31.191 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err: java.io.IOException: invalid preview surface
07-31 22:43:31.193 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
07-31 22:43:31.194 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:930)
07-31 22:43:31.194 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at com.example.karan.camera.MainActivity$1.onOpened(MainActivity.java:100)
07-31 22:43:31.195 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:139)
07-31 22:43:31.195 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
07-31 22:43:31.195 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
07-31 22:43:31.195 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
07-31 22:43:31.195 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
07-31 22:43:31.196 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-31 22:43:31.196 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
07-31 22:43:31.196 2852-2852/com.example.karan.camera W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Can anybody explain what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the same SurfaceView for both the media recorder output, as well as the camera output - they can't generally share.

And you're not sending any data from the camera to the media recorder, since you're not including a Surface from the MediaRecorder in your camera capture session.

Normally, what you want to do is to connect the camera to two surfaces - one for preview (to the SurfaceView) and one for recording (to the mediarecorder); you don't need to hook up the preview output of MediaRecorder at all, that's more for using MediaRecorder without a separate camera object.

Take a look at the official camera2 video recording sample for more details:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

Answer (score 0):

you should create a diffrent surface view for reecording a diffrent one for preview like this

```
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(),mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        Surface previewSurfice = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        Surface recordSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
```